# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined on Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, typeerror

I'm developing an app with express but I get this error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

      45 |
      46 |   if (!validate.pass)
    > 47 |      return res.status(400).send(
         |                             ^
      48 |              response(false, validate.errors, 'Error in request.')
      49 |      )
      50 |

      at ServerResponse.json (node_modules/express/lib/response.js:257:20)
      at ServerResponse.send (node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
      at Object.create (controllers/rideController.js:47:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__test__/rideController.test.js:32:10)
```

I don't get why get method is involved if I'm summoning send method.

The call of this is:

```
const res = require('express').response
...
ride.create({body: data}, res)
```

The functions are:

```
const rideRules = {
  rider: 'required|user',
  passenger: 'required|array',
  seats: 'required|integer',
  start_location: 'required|string',
  destination: 'required|string'
}

const errorsMessage = {
  'required.rider': "El conductor es necesario.",
  'required.passenger': "Los pasajeros son necesarios.",
  'required.seats': "El número de asientos disponibles es necesario.",
  'start_location': "El lugar de partida es necesario.",
  'destination': "El lugar de destino es necesario."
}

const create = (dataRide) => {
  const { rider, passenger, seats, start_location, destination } = dataRide
  return rides.create({
    rider: rider,
    passenger: passenger,
    available_seats: seats,
    status: 'En progreso',
    start_location: start_location,
    destination: destination,
    time: new Date(),
    ride_finished: false,
    comment: [{}]
  })
}

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const validate = validateIn(req.body, rideRules, errorsMessage)

  if (!validate.pass) 
    return res.status(400).send(
        response(false, validate.errors, 'Error in request.')
    )

  const rideInf = create(req.body)

  return res.status(200).send(response(true, rideInf, 'Ride created.'))
}
```

What I want is an unit test of create function.

The first problem I found was how to simulate a request and a response. As all I do with the request is using the property `body` I use a json and there's no more problem with this.

The current problem is the response.

Comment: can you post your express code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you are attempting to do with this:

```
const res = require('express').response
```

looks misguided.  The `.response` property on the Express object is not a live response object.  If you look at the [appropriate part of the Express code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L65), you can see that `require('express').response` is the response module (and all the things that it exports).  These are methods that will be used on a live response object, but are not yet on a live response object.  These are just exported methods that will eventually be attached to a live response object.  You can't use them in this way until they are attached to a live response object.

If you look further into [`./response.js` in the Express project](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L42), you see that `require('express').response` is actually a prototype derived from `http.ServerResponse.prototype` that Express will use later when it creates a live response object.

When you actually call `res.send()` on this prototype version of `res`, it appears that the first method it may actually call is in [this section of code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L132):

```
  if (!this.get('Content-Type')) {
```

Since `this` is incorrect when attempting to use the prototype this way, there would be no `.get()` method and you'd get the error you see.

---

Thus, when you then try to use that `res` object in the way that you would use a live response object, you will get some sort of error.  We'd have to be able to debug your exact code to explain why it complains exactly the way it does (perhaps there is a getter involved and thus the error message references `get` - that's just a guess).  But, it's fairly clear that `res` is not being used correctly.

If you show more of the context of your code (including the whole request handler), we can make more of a suggestion for how it should be written.  If you want more details on why the error comes out exactly the way it does, we'd need to be able to actually run that portion of your code to debug it and see what precisely is happening.  In any case, you need to change where you get `res` from.

---

To test your `create()` function that uses an http response object, you can either make a real http response object (involving a real http request/response) or create a mock http response object and hook the appropriate methods to see if the function does what it is supposed to.  You can read any number of articles [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20mock%20http%20response%20object%20javascript) on various ideas for mocking an http response object.

Comment: I don't get it, I tried it in an javascript's interpreter and res is not undefined, in fact, this was the only way I found to simulate an response.

Comment: @Francisco - Please show us the code for your WHOLE request handler and we can help further.  You cannot "simulate" an http response object in this way.  To do anything useful, it has to be attached to an actual http stream or be a full mock of a response object.  The variable `res` is often used in a different context in Express code as in `app.get("/somePath", (req, res) => {  res.send("something");});`.  That's where you should be getting a `res` object from.  You don't make one out of thin air.  It is given to you as part of an event system when there's an incoming http request.

Comment: @Francisco - I updated the answer to show a lot more detail and to show where the code can fail attempting to call `this.get()` which could generate the error you see.

Comment: @Francisco - Since I see you're probably new here, taking 4 hours to respond is not going to work very well here on stackoverflow.  This is a much more responsive place than other typical online forums.  If you're question is not entirely clear in the first 30 minutes after you post, you will miss most of the people that can help you.  I put a lot of effort into answering your original question (exactly why you were getting the error you were getting).  I think that question has now been thoroughly answered.  I added one more paragraph to my answer about testing your `create()` function.

Comment: @Francisco - If you have more specific questions about mocking an http request/response for testing purposes, I'd suggest you mark this question as done by accepting this answer (clicking checkmark to the left of the answer) and then start a new question with your more specific questions about testing your `create()` function.